# extend express Response type, and export my new type as a new module

Tags: typescript, express, npm, export

Im tring to create a new 'common' module for my team. 
one of the things it should include is an extension of the response and request object(of express).

we would like to achive 2 things - the first one is to extend Request to have property of user - that will intialize in a middleware that does all the authentication for us.

the second thing - we would like to create convention on how we return error, therfore I want to extend the reponse type of express, to have a method named sendError which will recive exception/ erormsg and will create the response. => i want to do more than just extend an inteface, I want to give it the implmention too.

so far I created a new module, in it I create a file  types.d.ts and added this file to my "types" in tsconfig.

```
import {User} from '../models/user.ts'
declare module 'express'{
    export interface Request {
user: User;
}
}
```

in my moudle, I can see the propery user for request, and everything works great.
the problem is when a service of ours install this module from the npm, it does not familiar with this property.

The seconed question, is how I achive my seconed traget ? it more the extending an interface, its more like extending a class, beacuse I want to give the implmention

I thought about somthing like that:

```
import {User} from '../models/user.ts'
declare module 'express'{
    export interface Response {
sendError: (statusCode : number, error :Error ) => void;
}
}

express.Response.sendError = //put the logic here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just extend the namespace? Here's what works for me:

I generally have a file `<project-root>/types/express.d.ts`. In your case the contents would be:

```
import {User} from '../models/user.ts'
declare namespace Express{
  export interface Request {
    user: User
  }

  export interface Response {
    sendError: (statusCode : number, error :Error ) => void;
  }
}
```

Check the [express DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts) to understand more